# How to add multiple values to a single key (Dictionaries in c#)

Tags: c#

Here I am retrieving leave type and leave profile from the database. Each leave_type might have more than one profile. So I made my leave types to be keys and my profiles to be values. When I am running my code I get an exception that says : 'An item with the same key has already been added.'
Please help

```
Dictionary<String, String> myDictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>();
            List<String[]> leave_result_list = new List<String[]>();
            StringBuilder leave_builder = new StringBuilder();`

            MySqlCommand leave_type_query = new MySqlCommand("SELECT leave_types.description, leave_profile.name FROM leave_types LEFT JOIN leave_profile on leave_types.type_id = leave_profile.leave_type_id", con);

            MySqlDataReader leave_type_reader = leave_type_query.ExecuteReader();
            while (leave_type_reader.Read())
            {
                string[] leave_type_and_profiles = new string[2];
                leave_type_and_profiles[0] = leave_type_reader.GetString("description");
                leave_type_and_profiles[1] = leave_type_reader.GetString("name");
                string leave_name = leave_type_and_profiles[0].ToString();
                string leave_profile = leave_type_and_profiles[1].ToString();
                myDictionary.Add(leave_name, leave_profile);
            }

            leave_type_reader.Close();
```

Comment: Well, if you want to have multiple strings per key in the dictionary, then the dictionary's value type needs to be some collection type for strings, such as List<T> for example. If implementing this scheme sounds like too much work for you and you are not strictly required to use a dictionary, there is always `NameValueCollection` in the barn waiting for you to use it instead... ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to have your value maybe as a string of arrays

Comment: "_string of arrays_"? Do you mean arrays of strings, perhaps?

Comment: Yhea sorry about that

Comment: Okay. Don't wish for arrays. Arrays have to be created with fixed size. There are functions for resizing arrays, but they technically don't resize an existing array but create a new array instance -- which would make a `Dictionary<string, string[]>`-based approach even messier than it has to be compared to using something like List<T> (which is not of fixed size but grows and shrinks with the items added to or removed from it).

Comment: Thank you so much, your responses are making me understand so much

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `Lookup` instead, which works like a dictionary but with a collection of values.

```
void Main()
{
    var lookup = GetTheStuff().ToLookup(x => x.leave_name, x => x.leave_profile)
}

private IEnumerable<(string leave_name, string leave_profile)> GetTheStuff()
{
    MySqlCommand leave_type_query = new MySqlCommand("SELECT leave_types.description, leave_profile.name FROM leave_types LEFT JOIN leave_profile on leave_types.type_id = leave_profile.leave_type_id", con);
    MySqlDataReader leave_type_reader = leave_type_query.ExecuteReader();
    
    while (leave_type_reader.Read())
    {
        string[] leave_type_and_profiles = new string[2];
        leave_type_and_profiles[0] = leave_type_reader.GetString("description");
        leave_type_and_profiles[1] = leave_type_reader.GetString("name");
        string leave_name = leave_type_and_profiles[0].ToString();
        string leave_profile = leave_type_and_profiles[1].ToString();
        yield return (leave_name, leave_profile)
    }

    leave_type_reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Each leave_type might have more than one profile

You should better use a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` then:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

while (leave_type_reader.Read())
{
    // ...
    if(myDictionary.TryGetValue(leave_name, out List<string> profiles))
        profiles.Add(leave_profile);
    else
        myDictionary.Add(leave_name, new List<string>{ leave_profile });
}
```

Comment: Sorry can you please explain the OUT please

Comment: @AngaMatsuluka: that's an [`out-parameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier). The `TryXY...` methods, like `int.TryParse`, `Dictionary.TryGetValue` and so on are most often implemented so. They return a `bool` indicating if the method was succesful and if so, the return the value as out-parameter. Here's the `TryGetValue`-docu: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-6.0